# Reference to SLG1 Log

Tags: logging, abap

I would like to have two logs. Log number one logs some basic information. It is a custom log because I need to filter by specific parameters. If log number one tells me that there was an error, I would like to save a reference to a more detailed `SLG1` log and open that log.

What is the unique identifier of a `SLG1` log I can use to display the log?

Answer (score 6):

Every application log instance has a log handle; (a GUID, type `BALLOGHNDL`) as well as an optional user-friendly external ID. For example, when you create a log using `BAL_LOG_CREATE`, exporting parameter `E_LOG_HANDLE` contains the handle of the instance you've just created.

If you'd like to work with two log instances at once (one summary, one detail), just keep track of the separate handles and refer to them appropriately when adding entries, displaying, etc.